# Use remote file server as data source in ansible

Tags: ansible, copy, fileserver

I am trying to use my file server in my local network as source for the rpm-packages I want to install later on the remote machine in the playbook.

For this I am using a simple apache web server where I have stored my packages under /var/www/httml/packages/*list-of-packages*

I think that it is possible to declare the ip of your file server with the equivalent hostname somewhere in a file and use that later in a playbook but I can not remember how exactly
like

At the end it should be looking like this:

```
src: {file-server}/packages/airtame/airtame.rpm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess you are looking at the fact that the package `name` of the [`yum module`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html) of ansible allows you to either:

- use a package name
- use an URL to the package
- use a local path to file to the package

> **name:** A package name or package specifier with version, like `name-1.0`.
>   If a previous version is specified, the task also needs to turn `allow_downgrade` on. See the `allow_downgrade` documentation for caveats with downgrading packages.
>   When using state=latest, this can be `'*'` which means run `yum -y update`.
>   **You can also pass a url or a local path to a rpm file (using state=present).** To operate on several packages this can accept a comma separated string of packages or (as of 2.0) a list of packages.

*Source:* https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html#parameters, emphasis mine.

**From the examples:**

```
- name: install the nginx rpm from a remote repo
  yum:
    name: http://nginx.org/packages/centos/6/noarch/RPMS/nginx-release-centos-6-0.el6.ngx.noarch.rpm
    state: present

- name: install nginx rpm from a local file
  yum:
    name: /usr/local/src/nginx-release-centos-6-0.el6.ngx.noarch.rpm
    state: present
```

*Source:* https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html#examples